# CSS media query text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been trying to make this webpage responsive. When I get down to about 970px the text stops adjusting. I set the left and right margin to 5% and made the font size smaller in the smaller queries but with this one the text doesn't break into a new line but instead creates a scroll bar. I can't figure out why this is happening only with the smaller queries and not the others. The live site is http://test.cloudhudl.com/contact-us/

This is what the larger query looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oswjs.jpg

This is what the smaller query looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF2mi.jpg

```
@media only screen
and (max-width : 1023px)
and (min-width : 768px) {

#main {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 2.5vw;
    margin-right: 2.5vw;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

        /* change overal size */
.social__container {
    font-size: .9em;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.email {
    border: solid 5px #FA7862;
    padding: 4% 0% 4% 0%;
    text-align: center;
}

.phone {
    margin-top: 8%;
    border: solid 5px #FA7862;
    padding: 4% 0% 4% 0%;
    text-align: center; 
}

/* Info Section */

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#info {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 45%;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

/*Form styles*/

.basic-grey {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    width: 70vw;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    float: both;
}
.basic-grey label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.basic-grey label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #888;
}
.basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"], .basic-grey textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #888;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
}
#message {
    padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
    height: 200px;

}
.basic-grey .button {

    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    background: #FA7862;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9E3F3F;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.basic-grey .button:hover {
    background: #CF7A7A;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem is here:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px)
#main {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 2.5vw;
    margin-right: 2.5vw;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

If you remove the margin values, the scrollbar should disappear.

The next problem is that weird positioning.  There's a trick you can do if you change the markup.  If you switch the places of the info div and the form in the HTML and then `float:right;` instead of `float:left;` on both, they'll change position.  Then when you hit the media query, you can get rid of the floats and the form will be on top of the contact info.

Comment: If I change info div and form div then they display in the wrong order at larger queries. I actually tried that before earlier. If I get rid of the margin the text doesn't adjust at all. http://imgur.com/Si1eNQX

Comment: If your width is 100% and you are adding margins to that, the scrollbars will appear because the box is being forced to expand larger than the window.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Si1eNQX This is what it looks like if I give it a width of 80% and no margins.

Comment: Sorry about that I change some of the code. If you shrink the screen you will see two problems still. The text still doesn't move to a new line when the screen is smaller and there is still a scroll bar even though no content is in the space to the right.

Comment: I don't get a horizontal scrollbar anymore.

Comment: I size is your browser at? I still have the scroll bar.

Comment: I'm resizing the browser horizontally and I can't get a scrollbar now.

Comment: Ok I don't have the scrollbar now but I have whitespace to the right of the content. http://imgur.com/Bgxi7P1

Comment: No problem, add `margin:0 auto;` to the main in that media query.

Comment: Wow... that was so much easier than I was making it. Thanks. I guess I just played with this for too long.